# Confusion in php object orientation

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, oop

I have some problem to realize how sub methods work in php .
for example I have a Method named `get` and it fetch some data from database . code is blow

```
/**
 * @param int $UserId
 * @return array
 */
public static function get($UserId)
{
    return Mysql::connection()->select($UserId);
}
```

I want to access array data using magic method named `__callStatic` and don't want to call get inside magic method . want to call magic method like this ->

```
FOO::get($UserId)->FirstName(); // FirstName is available in array which get method return
```

PS:  I don't know what this called in php programing and don't know how to do it . pls give me example .

Comment: If you have `public static function get($UserId) { ... }` then you can already call `FOO::get($UserId)` -- I'm confused as to why you'd want to force the use of `__callStatic` where you don't need it.

Comment: Ah ok I think I see what you're trying to do now. Adding a `__callStatic` to this class will not allow you to make fake method calls on the return value of the `get()` method because it is returning an array. If you want to chain method calls on the results of `get()`, then `get()` must return an object, and the class of that object must define a `FirstName()` method or a `__call()` method that intercepts it.

Comment: @AlexHowansky thanks ! that's the answer I look for